# JSON parse error in a system I didn't build

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, yui

I've recently been tasked with moving an intranet system from one, old server to a newer one. It uses a lot of the YUI library, as well as javascript/json which I have no experience with. When I try to load one of the pages (I can't link you to it, as its intranet) I get an error like this: (I have tried to print out any variables or things incase that helps.

```
e: SyntaxError: parseJSON
o: [object Object]
data: undefined
```

This error is brought up from the following try/catch:

```
var loadData = function(data) {
    if(data)
        data += '&offset=' + offset;
    else
        data = 'offset=' + offset;

    var callback = {
        success: function(o) {
            try {
                var data = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(o.responseText);
            } catch(e) { alert('e: ' + e + '\no: ' + o + '\ndata: ' + data}
```

I really don't know what json is about, but im assuming it isn't getting (the right) data from somewhere. Is the issue on this page or somewhere else?

Edit: I appreciate this may not be enough information required to troubleshoot, I don't know anything about JSON/YUI, just tell me if you need to know something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know what `o.responseText` is because `o` being `Object` doesn't really show what is the JSON string in question. Changing the alert to:

```
alert('e: ' + e + '\no.responseText: ' + o.responseText + '\ndata: ' + data);
```

might help diagnose the problem. No one can answer you whether the problem is is on that page or not unless you explain what is the JSON string and where it came from.

Comment: This is the code from those lines: So I'm assuming something is being posted there, but I dont know what...
    line 7:   $JSON = json_decode($_POST['JSON']);
 
    line 9:   if($JSON->Depot)
  $filter = " AND `Site` = '" . $JSON->Depot . "'";

Comment: Here you go, the problem is in dmrlist.php. Try reposting your question with a PHP tag and quoting PHP code because it seems like a problem with your PHP code and not JavaScript.

Comment: Ok thanks, Ill make a new question and reword to target at php/what I know now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like o.responseText is not valid JSON - can you print that out in your debug?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your hands on the responseText, you can run it through a JSON validator like http://jsonlint.com that will give you some idea of where the error is located.